# make two fields in serializer from a same model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using a nested serializer in another serializer and I have two models `Object` and `ObjectMedia` see the following code:

```
class ObjectMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    media_address = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectMedia
        fields = ["media_address", "type"]

class ObjectAddEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    object_medias = ObjectMediaSerializer(many=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = [
            "slug",
            "object_medias",
        ]
```

I want to add object media in two fields(separated by their type) like below but I don't know how it is possible:

```
{
  "slug":"my_slug",
  "object_media_type1": [
    {
      "media_address ": "somewhere",
       "type":TYPE1
    }
  ],
"object_media_type2": [
    {
      "media_address ": "somewhere",
       "type":TYPE2
    },
      {
      "media_address ": "somewhere\else",
       "type":TYPE2
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `SerializerMethodField`:

```py
class ObjectAddEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    object_media_type1 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    object_media_type2 = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_object_media_type1(self, instance):
        return ObjectMediaSerializer(instance.object_medias.filter(type="type1"), many=True).data

    def get_object_media_type2(self, instance):
        return ObjectMediaSerializer(instance.object_medias.filter(type="type2"), many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = [
            "slug",
            "object_media_type1",
            "object_media_type2",
        ]
```

Be aware that they are read-only. Official docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for read-only purpose with nested serializers:

```
class ObjectMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    media_address = serializers.SerializerMethodField()    
    class Meta:
        model = ObjectMedia
        fields = ["media_address", "type"]

class ObjectAddEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    object_medias_1 = ObjectMediaSerializer(source='your-fk-relation', many=True, required=True)
    object_medias_2 = ObjectMediaSerializer(source='your-fk-relation', many=True, required=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = [
            "slug",
            "object_medias_1",
            "object_medias_2",
        ]
```